# Overiding css using scss doesnt apply right styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I am having two versions of of same ant datepicker. First one just overrides the styling of the default antd styles, where in second one goes by writing the css in antd hierarchy and then adding the classes. The same thing works fine when using direct overriding , but when the same followed using hierarchy, styles arent matching up. Can someone help here to fix this discrepancies?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-breeze-6gmz85?file=/src/styles.scss:1518-1841

[image]

[image]

The first one is working one, the css for range and all is working just fine. It has curved corners. But second one has one cornered square and other one curved and also there is color change for the inbetween dates. Also How would I write the below css in the hierarchy mentioned in the notworking css.

Help would be really appreciated.

```
.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-range-start {
    &:not(.ant-picker-cell-range-start-single) {
        &::before {
            background-color: green !important;
        }
    }
}

.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-range-end {
    &:not(.ant-picker-cell-range-end-single) {
        &::before {
            background-color: green !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: what if you add this at the end of your styles.scss?

```
.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-selected {
  &.ant-picker-cell-selected {
    background-color:transparent !important;
  }
}
.custom-datepicker-dropdown {
  .ant-picker-panel-container {
    .ant-picker-panel {
      .ant-picker-date-panel {
        .ant-picker-body {
          .ant-picker-content {
            .ant-picker-cell {
              &.ant-picker-cell-in-view{
                &.ant-picker-cell-in-range {
                  .ant-picker-cell-inner {
                    color: white !important
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Solution 2: update your first declaration to this:

```
.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-range-start {
  background:transparent !important;
    &:not(.ant-picker-cell-range-start-single) {
        &::before {
            background-color: green !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding the font color issue: unfortunately there is no way to target the range cells with neither of your declarations because those are both cells in a table and the cells in the range span over multiple table rows. You would have to target a parent element (of your element) and then it's children and that's not possible. So you need a new declaration maybe something more simple than my first solution. Add this at the end of styles.scss:

```
.ant-picker-cell-in-range {
 .ant-picker-cell-inner {
      color: white !important
  }
}
```

Comment: Still this is not solving the issue.The range picker is acting weird

Comment: @li97 if I add those to styles.scss I see it's working ok. Maybe I'm missing smth. What do you mean by acting weird.